# How to make a Query formula in Google Sheets for an inventory per month columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a dashboard in google sheets for my inventory. i am using query function to populate a section of the dashboard with data as a summary. my source data is set up as item name, type, january, february, march, april, may.... with quantities of the items as values under the months. i want the summary in the dashboard to show only the item, type and total quantity in a month as specified by a field from a list.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1juEwOLFrlwuI7GUtwckZW8AEDPsTXfF9AAdf5vxKBpg/edit?usp=sharing

my current formula

```
=query(A1:L12,"select B,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L where A='"&$B14&"'",1)
```

if i search from my dropdown list...
Month: January
Item: AAA
I want to show only the item's 'type' followed by the month I searched for and the corresponding quantities.
right now, my query formula would show me all the month, when i only want to see the one I specified in the "search".

Comment: We can't access your spreadsheet. Please fix permissions.

Comment: link access is back. i apologize for the mix up

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=query({A2:B12, filter(D2:L12, D1:L1=B15)}, "Select Col2, Col3 where Col1 = '"&B14&"'")
```